# MySQL syntax error, can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

Hello and thanks for reading my question! I am receiving a syntax error with this code but I cannot figure out what's wrong. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
mysql> create table match (
-> event_id int not null,
-> player1_id int,
-> player2_id int,
-> player1_score int,
-> player2_score int,
-> winner_id int,
-> foreign key (event_id) references event(id)
-> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'match (
event_id int not null,
player1_id int,
player2_id int,
player1_score int' at line 1
```

I can't find any missing commas, and the event table definitely exists with an id column. Any ideas what I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: Match is a reserved word - a poor choice for a table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Enclose it in backticks:

```
create table `match` ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I was googling around because I thought that might be the case but couldn't find it. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: It's worth checking that keyword list now and then for ideas on what not to name tables and columns. It can be annoying when it's the term you want to use, but it's a lot less annoying than a conflict that necessitates escaping like this every single time you reference it.